# Why won't my linkbutton in gridview work?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

[image]

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="View_remove_children.aspx.cs" Inherits="Coursework.View_remove_children" %>

[image: EDIT - Screenshot of error!]

I am currently trying to create an asp.net web app in c# using Visual Studio. I have a grid view, displaying some fields from a database table and have added a column with 'Delete' linkbuttons to enable the user to delete a table entry. After trying various solutions, I am receiving an error when clicking on any of the delete linkbuttons when running my app. I have a feeling that the problem lies within the source code but none of the solutions I found online have worked. I have included both my .cs code as well as my source code. The problem seems to be that it isn't recognizing that i'm using linkbuttons, even though I am. If anyone can spot where I am going wrong, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT - [I should add that I am using this guide to try to implement a delete feature in my gridview, if that helps at all.](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Select-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-ASPNet-GridView-control.aspx)

[image: Error when clicking any of the delete link buttons]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;


namespace Coursework
{
public partial class View_remove_children : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    public void BindData()
    {
        string strQuery = "select firstname, dob, childID" +
                           " from children";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    protected void OnPaging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }     
    protected void UpdateCustomer(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string firstname = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("firstnameLbl")).Text;
        string dob = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dobLbl")).Text;
        string childID = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("childIDlbl")).Text;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update children set childID=@childID,firstname=@firstname " +
         "where childID=@childID;" +
         "select firstname, dob, childID from children";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = firstname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dob;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@childID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = childID;
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void Gridview1_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from  children where " +
        "childID=@childID;" +
         "select firstname, dob, childID from children";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@childID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lnkRemove.CommandArgument;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: In your delete use GridViewDeleteEventArgs e instead of the sender. It will have a rowindex value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but I am fairly new to c# and .net so having trouble understanding your meaning. Are you saying delete the "LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;" line and if so, what should I replace it with? Thanks again.

Comment: string childID = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("childIDlbl")).Text; As at the moment your action is wired to a gridview.

Comment: When I add your line of code, I get the following error when clicking delete on the gridview. ----An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Coursework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.----

Comment: I assumed your code to retrieve childId was working. GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]; this should give you the selected row.

Comment: I started off following a guide I was linked to by someone on here, but i've been making changes based off of other articles/people on here and now my code is a bit of a mess and I don't know what to do. I commented out the first piece of code you gave me, along with the linkbutton sender code and used your latest line of code. It now gives me the following error. ----An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@childID".----

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130355/discussion-between-acostea-and-r-quijano).